# Flask Redirection with Gunicorn & nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

My flask is showing a strange redirection behavior. I don't know what I am doing wrong. All of my `html files` work fine if I load them as the `'/' route`, but redirection doesn't work right and I get the following error message:

```
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
DNS address could not be found
```

The error can also be reproduced with the following 4 routes:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'The index page'

@app.route('/projects/')
def projects():
    return 'The project page'

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return 'The about page'

@app.route('/main')
def main():
    return 'The main page'
```

No 1 will work, when typing just the server ip into the browser.

No 2 will work like this: ip/projects/ but not liek this ip/projects

No 3 works like this: ip/about but not like this ip/about/

No 4 doesn't work at all! Why?

I am runnung gunicorn with nginx as proxy. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`/abc/` and `/abc` are two different routes from a routing perspective. But you can always tell flask that, that is not what you want. You can do a global change in your code us the app object

```
app.url_map.strict_slashes = False
```

or you can do a `route` base mapping of such behavior using `strict_slashes=False`

```
@app.route('/projects/', strict_slashes=False)
def projects():
    return 'The project page'
```

Now #4 may not be working because of the method name. So change

```
@app.route('/main')
def main():
    return 'The main page'
```

to

```
@app.route('/main')
def main_route():
    return 'The main page'
```